# Angular 8 Get URL params (HttpParams) encoded with % for special caracters

Tags: angular, api, http, encoding, character

I'm searching for cancel the default decoding of HttpParams of angular :

In the URL: ?categories=first%2Bsecond

and then when i get HttpParams and call an API with categories : ?categories=first+second

But i don't want %2B to be encoded like that, i need to call the API with %2B

There is many subjects about this issue but all set manually params and not me, i get params and call an API after

i found encodeURIComponent but i really don't know how to get params and re-encode them

i try this :

```
    if (params) {
  params.keys().forEach((key: string) => {
    if(key == 'categories'){
      console.log("i'm here");
      
    }
    request[key] = params.get(key);
  });
}
```

But in the condition i don't know how to re encode params

Ty :)

Comment: Setting as a string might do the trick but would be a work around.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually working :

```
        console.log(params);
    const categories = [];
    let newParams = new HttpParams();
    let test = new HttpParams();

    if (params) {
      params.keys().forEach((key: string) => {

        if(key == "categories") {

          for (let index = 0; index < params.get(key).length; index++) {
            categories.push(encodeURIComponent(params.get(key)[index]));
          }

          newParams = params.delete(key);

          categories.forEach(categorie => {
            newParams = newParams.append(key, categorie);
          });
          console.log(newParams);
        }
      });
    }
```

But when i used new newParams like that :

```
    const url = `${BASE_URL}/${`api/${id}/random`}`;
return this.http.get<Page<Element>>(url, {params});
```

The '+' that has been correctly encoded in %2B before become %252 in the api call